# History of 14 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)The Jews of Chevron Where save from a decree from the Pasha to give him 50,000 Piasters or be expelled after 3 days of fasting and Davening the Money showed up in the Window and it became a WINDOW PURIM in Chevron in 1740

2)The Jews where expelled from Laibach, Austria in 1515

3)Population of Israel reached three million in  1971

4)Yahertzits

-Reb Aryeh Leib Bakst Rosh Yeshiva of Ateres Mordichai Detroit

- R' Reuven Dov Dessler (1935) father of R' Eliyahu Dessler
- R' Tzvi Hirsh of Teplik (1928), Breslover Tzadik
- R' Mordechai Twersky of Lavoi (1905)

-Pinchas Rutenberg (1879-1942), founder of the Israel Electric Corporation.He was  A Russian Jewish immigrant,Rutenberg's flagship project was a hydroelectric plant on the Jordan River in 1931, which he built with Winston Churchill's political backing and Baron Edmond de Rothschild's financial support. In 1948, the plant was eventually destroyed by the Arab 
Legion

From Aish.com